# MariaDB server is down after reboot

Tags: mariadb

I needed to know my mariadb version but there's a typo `mysqld -version` (I installed it via apt, it was working with cli login, but not mysqli). The command jammed and I forced reboot the VPS from the panel. When it went up, I could not start mariadb.

```
● mariadb.service - MariaDB 10.3.34 database server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mariadb.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2022-03-12 16:43:54 CET; 23min ago
       Docs: man:mysqld(8)
             https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/systemd/
    Process: 563 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/install -m 755 -o mysql -g root -d /var/run/mysqld (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Process: 598 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c systemctl unset-environment _WSREP_START_POSITION (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Process: 628 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c [ ! -e /usr/bin/galera_recovery ] && VAR= ||   VAR=`cd /usr/bin/..; /usr/bin/galera_recovery`; [ $? -eq 0 ]   && systemctl set-environment _WSREP_START_POSITION=$VAR || exit 1 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Process: 692 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld $MYSQLD_OPTS $_WSREP_NEW_CLUSTER $_WSREP_START_POSITION (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Main PID: 692 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
     Status: "MariaDB server is down"

Mar 12 16:43:53 myvps systemd[1]: Starting MariaDB 10.3.34 database server...
Mar 12 16:43:53 myvps mysqld[692]: 2022-03-12 16:43:53 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 10.3.34-MariaDB-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) starting as process 692 ...                                                   Mar 12 16:43:54 myvps systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Mar 12 16:43:54 myvps systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Mar 12 16:43:54 myvps systemd[1]: Failed to start MariaDB 10.3.34 database server
```

Comment: The disk is far from full.

Answer (score 0):

I saw this:
`[ERROR] InnoDB: Missing MLOG_CHECKPOINT at 1630019 between the checkpoint 1630019 and the end 1630028.`
I read this.
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/163445/innodb-ignoring-the-redo-log-due-to-missing-mlog-checkpoint
I did this
`rm /var/lib/mysql/ib_logfile*`
And worked for me.